# How can I change my chapter from "INTRODUCTION" to "1 INTRODUCTION"

Tags: chapters

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{report} 
\usepackage{Times} %TIMES ROMANS FORMAT
\usepackage{titlesec}
\titleformat{\chapter}[display]
{\normalfont\bfseries\centering}{}{0pt}{\Huge}
%\titlespacing*{\chapter}{0pt}{-10pt}{40pt}
\usepackage{lipsum}  
\renewcommand{\chaptername}{CHAPTER}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\fancyhf{}
\fancyhead[C]{\thepage}
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}
\pagestyle{fancy}
\usepackage{tocloft}
\setlength{\cftchapnumwidth}{3em}
\cftsetindents{section}{3em}{1.5em}
\cftsetindents{subsection}{4.5em}{2.5em}
\fancypagestyle{plain}{%
    \fancyhf{} % clear all header and footer fields
    \fancyhead[C]{\thepage} % except the center
}
\setcounter{tocdepth}{2}
\setcounter{secnumdepth}{3}
\begin{document}
    
    \chapter{INTRODUCTION} 
    
    \section{Chapter Overview}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like this, I did few changes due to the package `times` and `fancyhdr`.

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{report} 
%\usepackage{times} %TIMES ROMANS FORMAT % package is obsolete, use mathptmx
\usepackage{mathptmx}
\usepackage{titlesec}
\titleformat{\chapter}[hang]
{\Huge\bfseries\centering}{\thechapter\space}{0pt}{\Huge}
%\titlespacing*{\chapter}{0pt}{-10pt}{40pt}
\usepackage{lipsum}  
\renewcommand{\chaptername}{CHAPTER}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\fancyhf{}
\fancyhead[C]{\thepage}
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}
\setlength{\headheight}{14.49998pt} % get rid of warning from fancyhdr
\pagestyle{fancy}
\usepackage{tocloft}
\setlength{\cftchapnumwidth}{3em}
\cftsetindents{section}{3em}{1.5em}
\cftsetindents{subsection}{4.5em}{2.5em}
\fancypagestyle{plain}{%
    \fancyhf{} % clear all header and footer fields
    \fancyhead[C]{\thepage} % except the center
}
\setcounter{tocdepth}{2}
\setcounter{secnumdepth}{3}
\begin{document}
\chapter{INTRODUCTION} 
\section{Chapter Overview}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Your preamble is very confusing, I'd say.

The main problem is that you never tell `titlesec` to use the chapter number anywhere. Use `block` for the style, because this way you will have the number next to the title.

I modified your preamble to better separate package loading and settings.

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{report} 

\usepackage{times} %TIMES ROMANS FORMAT
\usepackage{titlesec}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{tocloft}

\usepackage{lipsum}  

%% titlesec
\titleformat{\chapter}[block]
  {\normalfont\Huge\bfseries\filcenter}
  {\thechapter}% <----- HERE
  {0.5em}
  {}
%\titlespacing*{\chapter}{0pt}{-10pt}{40pt}

%% fancyhdr
\fancyhf{}
\fancyhead[C]{\thepage}
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}
\pagestyle{fancy}
\fancypagestyle{plain}{%
    \fancyhf{}% clear all header and footer fields
    \fancyhead[C]{\thepage}% except the center
}
\setlength{\headheight}{14.5pt}% <--- as per warning

%% tocloft
\setlength{\cftchapnumwidth}{3em}
\cftsetindents{section}{3em}{1.5em}
\cftsetindents{subsection}{4.5em}{2.5em}

%% general settings
%\renewcommand{\chaptername}{CHAPTER}
\setcounter{tocdepth}{2}
\setcounter{secnumdepth}{3}

\begin{document}
    
\chapter{INTRODUCTION} 
    
\section{Chapter Overview}

\end{document}
```

I left `times` (note the lowercase), but you should consider better packages supporting Times. If you need math, you can choose between `\usepackage{newtx}` or `\usepackage{stix2}`.

[image]